# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_app.default.auth') FIREBASE REACT NATIVE EXPO

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo, react-native-firebase

I hear that Firebase is great and I'm finally adding it to one of my React Native projects, but keep getting import errors or errors with the methods. Has anyone come across this issue?

Here is the firebase.js file:

```
 
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
// import firebase from 'firebase'
import '@firebase/auth';
// import '@firebase/firestore';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: 
    authDomain: 
    projectId: 
    storageBucket: 
    messagingSenderId: 
    appId: 
};

// Initialize Firebase
// !firebase.apps.length
//     ? firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
//     : firebase.app()
initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// const db = firebase.firestore()
export default firebase
```

Here is the LoginForm.js file:

```
import { View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Text, Pressable, Alert } from 'react-native'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Formik } from 'formik'
import * as Yup from 'yup'
import Validator from 'email-validator'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'


const LoginForm = ({ navigation }) => {
    const LoginFormSchema = Yup.object().shape({
        email: Yup.string().email().required('An email is required'),
        password: Yup.string()
            .required()
            .min(8, 'Your password must have at least 8 characters')
    })
    const onLogin = async (email, password) => {
        try {
            await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            console.log("firebase login successful", email, password)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            Alert.alert(error.message)
        }
    }
    return (
        <View style={styles.wrapper} >
            <Formik
                initialValues={{ email: '', password: '' }}
                onSubmit={values => {
                    onLogin(values.email, values.password)
                    console.log(values)
                }}
                validationSchema={LoginFormSchema}
                validateOnMount={true}
            >
                {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values, isValid }) => (
                    <>
                        <View style={[styles.inputField, {
                            borderColor: values.email.length < 1 ||
                                Validator.validate(values.email) ? '#ccc' : 'red'
                        }
                        ]}>
                            <TextInput
                                placeholderTextColor='#444'
                                placeholder='Phone number, username or email'
                                autoCapitalize='none'
                                keyboardType='email-address'
                                textContentType='emailAddress'
                                autoFocus={true}
                                onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
                                onBlur={handleBlur('email')}
                                value={values.email}
                            />
                        </View>
                        <View style={[styles.inputField, {
                            borderColor:
                                1 > values.password.length || values.password.length >= 6
                                    ? '#ccc' : 'red'
                        }
                        ]}>
                            <TextInput
                                placeholderTextColor='#444'
                                placeholder="Password"
                                autoCapitalize='none'
                                autoCorrect={false}
                                secureTextEntry={true}
                                textContentType='password'
                                onChangeText={handleChange('password')}
                                onBlur={handleBlur('password')}
                                value={values.password}
                            />
                        </View>
                        <View style={{ alignItems: 'flex-end', marginBottom: 30, }}>
                            <Text style={{ color: '#6BB0F5' }}>Forgot password?</Text>
                        </View>
                        <Pressable style={styles.button(isValid)}
                            titleSize={20}
                            disabled={!isValid}
                            onPress={handleSubmit}>
                            <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 18, fontWeight: '700' }}>Log in</Text>
                        </Pressable>
                        <View style={styles.signup}>
                            <Text>Don't have an account?</Text>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.push('SignUpScreen')}>
                                <Text style={{ color: '#6BB0F5' }}> Sign up</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </>
                )}
            </Formik>
        </View>
    )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    wrapper: {
        marginTop: 80,
    },
    inputField: {
        borderRadius: 20,
        padding: 10,
        backgroundColor: "#FAFAFA",
        marginBottom: 10,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'gray'

    },
    button: (isValid) => ({
        backgroundColor: isValid ? '#0096F6' : '#9ACAF7',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        minHeight: 42,
        borderRadius: 4,
    }),
    signup: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        width: '100%',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        marginTop: 50,
    }
})
export default LoginForm
```

I've tried importing firebase the older way using *, firebase/compat/app as well. If anyone has a good solution for this situation please feel free to share. Thanks!

Comment: This is the full error:
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_app.default.auth')
at components/login/LoginForm.js:18:18 in onLogin
at components/login/LoginForm.js:16:20 in onLogin
at components/login/LoginForm.js:30:27 in Formik.props.onSubmit
at node_modules/formik/dist/formik.cjs.development.js:864:44 in validateFormWithHighPriority.then$argument_0

Comment: What is your Firebase version?

Comment: "firebase": "^9.6.7",
I installed using expo install firebase

Comment: Firebase V9 API is now modular instead being a namespace -  Refer docs  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#sign_up_new_users